# How do I alignBaseline to bottom line of multi-line TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two TextViews side by side. Let's say the left TextView is 1 line and the right TextView is 2 lines. Is there any way to align the *baselines* of the left TextView with the last line in the right TextView?

I'm open to using whatever layout (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, etc.) that can accomplish this.

(The default behavior of `android:layout_alignBaseline` in Android is that it aligns the baselines of the top lines.)

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could accomplish this with RelativeLayout if you implement a custom TextView. Specifically, you could override [TextView.getBaseline](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#5970) like so:

```
package mypackage.name;

// TODO: imports, etc.

public class BaselineLastLineTextView extends TextView {
    // TODO: constructors, etc.

    @Override
    public int getBaseline() {
        Layout layout = getLayout();
        if (layout == null) {
            return super.getBaseline();
        }
        int baselineOffset = super.getBaseline() - layout.getLineBaseline(0);
        return baselineOffset + layout.getLineBaseline(layout.getLineCount()-1);
    }
}
```

Then you would use your custom TextView inside a RelativeLayout as follows:

```
<mypackage.name.BaselineLastLineTextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_1"
    <!-- TODO: other TextView properties -->
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_2"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/text_view_1"
    <!-- TODO: other TextView properties -->
/>
```

Comment: It's pretty burdensome to have to create a custom TextView, but this is definitely a smart solution. Thanks. I didn't try it out, but seems like it'll work.

Answer (score -3):

I guess a `RelativeLayout` would do it.

```
<RelativeLayout..>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:maxLines="2"
        ... />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tv2"
        android:maxLines="1"
        ... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is aligning bottom, not baseline.

Comment: Use `android:layout_alignBaseline`

Comment: @LittleChild `alignBaseline` aligns to the first line, not the bottom line.