# Align TextView to another multiline TextView bottom line

Tags: android, android-xml

I want to achieve the below effect (ignore the buttons, only see the gray and blue texts):
[image: 2 TextViews]

First textView is multilined, I don't know in advance the possible text length.

Second TextView is "edit", I want it to be able to react to taps (also ripple background etc).

I know I can align baselines of TextViews in constraint layout, but this will align to the first textView's top line.

Any suggestion would be welcome.
Preferred: a way to do this in XML.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you add the "edit" text to the end of the string and make it clickable? You can do that by using spannable. 

I don't think you can achieve that effect by using XML logic only, at least not in a hacky way, the constraint attaches to the end of the textview and that will be always the larger width.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57610578/multi-line-text-views-alignment-to-their-baseline-constraintlayout-android-stud).

Comment: thanks for the replies! I would like the "edit" to be clickable and also have a ripple BG effect. I can use your link for the clickable part, and I will play around with it to see if I can add some ripple BG. if youo can point for a usefull way for the ripple that would be awesome!